# How separators prevent electrons from passing through

Tags: batteries

Separators (polymers) in batteries keep electrons from passing through but they let ions through. How do they do that if electrons are smaller than ions? Can we imagine it as a kind of 3D wire mesh whose molecular configuration repel electrons?

Comment: I'm a little fuzzy on the physics, but my understanding is that the electrolyte in which these polymer separators are used only 'conducts' by means of 'ion flow'. Electrons aren't free to move in this electrolyte, so it doesn't matter that they *could* pass through the separator - they don't.

Comment: @brhans So it's the electrolyte that forms the real barrier, huh?